# Creating a directory tree and feed it as an input to create the same tree again

Tags: python-3.x, directory, automation

I am trying to get the directory tree only from a root folder in a server. Then feed the output to another program so it will create the same structure to another server.

The hard way is to create a JSON like structure of tree and then parse it to another server and create folders.

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why JSON? You could create just list of directories, e.g. with this script:

```
import os

def print_dir(path):
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_dir():
                d = os.path.join(path, entry.name)
                yield d
                yield from print_dir(d)

for d in print_dir('/'):
    print(d)
```

This prints whole directory tree from root ('`/`'):

```
/lib
/lib/crda
/lib/crda/pubkeys
/lib/terminfo
/lib/terminfo/m
/lib/terminfo/c
/lib/terminfo/x
/lib/terminfo/E
...etc.
```

You then send this list to the server, where you will read it line by line and run `mkdir` with `-p` argument (create parents, no error if existing, make parent directories as needed).

Comment: Is there any way to get the last level of dirs only. So I don't have to create `/lib` then again `/lib/crda`, rather just `/lib/crda` will handle both cases.